# VSTO Outlook add-in Dll's locked by outlook(16) after Version 1708 (Build 8431.2094)

Tags: outlook, vsto

**Outlook behavior change**: After the recent patch from MS on Outlook 16 version 1708 (Build 8431.2094) the behavior of how it handles VSTO Dll's has been changed. Earlier if any outlook VSTO add-in is installed its respective VSTO Dll's were cached in any temp folder created by outlook itself but after this patch these Dll's are used directly from the installation path rather than from a cached location.

**Issue because of this change**: Due to this change the update process is become a difficult task. Now for any VSTO add-in patch to apply we need to uninstall the older Dll's or replace those with new Dll's. In this process if outlook is opened then it has locked down the older VSTO Dll's and doesn't allow the replacement to happen. So the only way is to close outlook and do the update. But most of the installs happen in quite/silent mode which doesn't prompt the GUI to user and close the outlook abruptly. This is a bad user experience and user might also loose his savings and need machine restart to reflect the new updates of add-in which were earlier taking effect after just outlook restart.

Comment: I am surprised you were ever able to update a VSTO addin while Outlook is still running. Closing and reopening Outlook does not seem to be a huge limitation.